# In how many ways to NOT take a red ball in an urn?

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, inclusion-exclusion

There are 25 balls in five different colors in an urn. The balls are numbered 1 to 5 in each color. I.e. they are all unique.

In how many ways can I take 10 balls without returning any of them and I DON'T get any red ball.

Maybe I make this harder than it is. I've trying to solve it by inclusion-exclusoin and generating functions but I don't really get any reasonable answer.

By generating functions i tried to solve that I take at least one red ball and subtract that from $25 \choose 10$ that is the total ways of choosing 10 balls.

My first try was something like this where every x represent the different colors and $x_1$ is the red.

$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 10$

$1 \leq x_1 \leq 5, \\  0 \leq x_i \leq 5 , \\ 2 \leq i \leq 5$

From this we get

$5 + 9 - 1 \choose 9$ = 715.

I didnt like that answer so I tried something else.

$x(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5)^4=10$

And from that, by $\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$ we get

$x \cdot (\frac{1-x^5}{1-x})(\frac{1-x^6}{1-x})^{^4} = 10 $

calculating the coefficient of 10 we get 505 and that doesn't either feel right.

By inclusion - exclusion:

${25 \choose 10} - {24 \choose 9} + {23 \choose 8} - + - \dots $ But here I dont take respect to the red balls in any way.

My thought is to perhaps divide the problem into different cases, like

I take one red ball 
I take two red balls
$\vdots$

And make something from that but now I am pretty confused generally.

Comment: What have you performed?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please edit the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need red balls, this boils down to a simpler problem: "in how many ways can I fetch 10 balls out of an urn with 20 unique balls in it". If order isn't important, this is simple:

$${20 \choose 10} = \frac{20!}{10!10!}$$

Comment: Is it really that simple? There are an awful lot of ways to pick them there.. 670 billion. 

When i compute that I want to pick 10 out of 25 balls I use $25 \choose 10$ and get around 3.7 million.  
There couldn't be more ways to pick 10 out of 20 than 10 out of 25..

Order is not relevant and repetitions are not allowed. Should I use another method?

Comment: $\frac {20!}{10! \times 10!}$ , not $\frac {20!}{10! }$

Comment: @Haiku, since order isn't important, then as Lourrran says - there has to be another $\frac{1}{10!}$. I'll correct my answer. Where did you get 670 billion - what does this number mean? ${25 \choose 10} = 3268760$, ${20 \choose 10} = 184756$

Comment: @Haiku yes it's that simple. If you don't want red ball then simply take anything but red ball. Don't overcomplicate things

Comment: Sorry I meant 3.27 million. and 670 billion came from $\frac{20!}{10!}$. 

That's a good advice! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you do not select any red balls, then you must select $10$ of the remaining $25 - 5 = 20$ balls, which can be done in
$$\binom{20}{10}$$
ways.

As a sanity check, observe that the number of ways of selecting exactly $k$ of the five red balls and $10 - k$ of the remaining $20$ balls is
$$\binom{5}{k}\binom{20}{10 - k}$$
Hence, the total number of selections is
$$\binom{5}{0}\binom{20}{10} + \binom{5}{1}\binom{20}{9} + \binom{5}{2}\binom{20}{8} + \binom{5}{3}\binom{20}{7} + \binom{5}{4}\binom{20}{6} + \binom{5}{5}\binom{20}{5} = \binom{25}{5}$$
which can be checked by direct calculation or by applying [Vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity).